# FutureBuilder operated without initState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I work with FutureBuilder to view a set of data through GridView by FutureBuilder but there are one problem the data is view  without put method  in initState().I don't know why it works without putting it in initState().

full code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  bool showicon = false;
  var apiURL;
  Future getdataCat() async {
    setState(() {
      showicon = true;
    });
    apiURL = '***********************';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiURL));
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (responsebody.length > 0) {
      return responsebody;
    } else {
      showicon = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getdataCat(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    // still waiting for data to come
                    return showicon
                        ? Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ))
                        : SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/data.png',
                            )));
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
                      snapshot.data.isEmpty &&
                      snapshot.data <= 0) {
                    return SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/data.png',
                        )));
                  } else {
                    return GridView.builder(
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 3.4),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Card(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Flexible(
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                    Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                            "${snapshot.data[index]['name']}"))
                                  ]),
                                )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I not make any thing in initState() but it's still working.

I need to stop it if I don't put it in initState().Because I need to run a different function before it.

Comment: If it's working then what is your problem? please provide more info.

Comment: Hi bro / I was say that/  I  need to stop it if I don't put it in initState() @HamaSabah

Comment: Because I need to run a different function before it @HamaSabah

Comment: I think you can modify the code by creating a future variable that will be assigned on `future:here`  And no need to have extra things to handle other cases,

Comment: Hi bro Can you share some code please @YeasinSheikh

Comment: What @YeasinSheikh is true, if you want to call your method in the initState() you need to create another variable to hold the data that will be returned. Here is an article of how to use FutureBuilder properly: https://blog.devgenius.io/understanding-futurebuilder-in-flutter-491501526373

Comment: You can check  Randal L. Schwartz video as well, I've included on my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this way. You can check [Randal L. Schwartz video](https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg)

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final Future<List<int>?> myFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = getCatData();
  }

  Future<List<int>?> getCatData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    //your operations

    return [1, 2, 5];
    // return [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {});
      }),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<int>?>(
                future: myFuture,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }

                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("Error ${snapshot.error}");
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text("no Data found");
                  }
                  if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                    return Text("Empty found");
                  }

                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: 3.4,
                      ),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                            child: Text(snapshot.data[index].toString()));
                      },
                    );
                  }

                  return Text("NA");
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also do `late final Future<List<int>?> myFuture= getCatData();`

Answer (score 0):

Point of FutureBuilder is to run a function that will return with the data you want to use to build your widgets.

You already call your method in the FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: getdataCat(),
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {...}
)
```

Comment: Hello brother / yes but I need to stop it I may need to do a different procedure before it works